# Is there a way to avoid longitude location to be null

Tags: java, android, error-handling

I am trying to run a code that works like a weather app but after writing the code I am getting java null pointer error
Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.nishal.wheatherapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout homeRl;
    private ProgressBar loadingPB;
    private TextView cityNameTV,temperatureTV,conditionTV;
    private RecyclerView weatherRV;
    private TextInputEditText cityEdt;
    private ImageView backIV,iconIV,searchIV;
    private ArrayList<WeatherRvModel> weatherRvModelArrayList;
    private WeatherRVAdapter weatherRVAdapter;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private  int PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    private String cityName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        homeRl = findViewById(R.id.idRLHome);
        loadingPB = findViewById(R.id.idPBLoading);
        cityNameTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVCityName);
        cityEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtCity);
        temperatureTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVTemparature);
        conditionTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVCondition);
        weatherRV = findViewById(R.id.idRVweather);
        backIV = findViewById(R.id.idIVBack);
        iconIV = findViewById(R.id.IVIcon);
        searchIV = findViewById(R.id.idIVSearch);
        weatherRvModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        weatherRVAdapter = new WeatherRVAdapter(this,weatherRvModelArrayList);
        weatherRV.setAdapter(weatherRVAdapter);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_CODE);
        }

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            cityName = getCityName(location.getLongitude(),location.getLatitude());
            getWeatherInfo(cityName);
        searchIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String city = cityEdt.getText().toString();
                if(city.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter City Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    cityNameTV.setText(cityName);
                    getWeatherInfo(city);
                }
            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode==PERMISSION_CODE){
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Provide the Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getCityName(double longitude, double latitude){
        String cityName = "Not Found";
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try{
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,10);
            for(Address adr : addresses){
                if(adr!=null){
                    String city = adr.getLocality();
                    if(city!=null && !city.equals("")){
                        cityName = city;
                    }else{
                        Log.d("TAG","CITY NOT FOUND");
                        Toast.makeText(this,"User City Not Found..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cityName;
    }
    //City name entry
    private void getWeatherInfo(String cityName){
        String url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=f7d844c25670438f8aa122034230208&q="+ cityName +"&days=1&aqi=yes&alerts=yes";
        cityNameTV.setText(cityName);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                homeRl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                weatherRvModelArrayList.clear();
                try {
                    String temperature = response.getJSONObject("current").getString("temp_c");
                    temperatureTV.setText(temperature+"°c");
                    int isDay = response.getJSONObject("current").getInt("is_day");
                    String condition = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("text");
                    String conditionIcon = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("icon");
                    Picasso.get().load("http:".concat(conditionIcon)).into(iconIV);
                    conditionTV.setText(condition);
                    if(isDay==1){
                        //morning
                        Picasso.get().load("https://unsplash.com/photos/hqvP1DMi0d0").into(backIV);
                    }else{
                        //night
                        Picasso.get().load("https://unsplash.com/photos/rpVQJbZMw8o").into(backIV);
                    }

                    JSONObject forecastObj = response.getJSONObject("forecast");
                    JSONObject forecastO = forecastObj.getJSONArray("forecastday").getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray hourArray = forecastO.getJSONArray("hour");

                    for(int i=0;i<hourArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject hourObj = hourArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String time = hourObj.getString("time");
                        String temper = hourObj.getString("temp_c");
                        String img = hourObj.getJSONObject("condition").getString("icon");
                        String wind = hourObj.getString("wind_kph");
                        weatherRvModelArrayList.add(new WeatherRvModel(time,temper,img,wind));
                    }
                    weatherRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter valid City Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

}
```

I tried all the methods but it is still giving me
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLongitude()' this error

my logcat  is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLongitude()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
```

Comment: `location` is `null`, meaning `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation` returned `null`.

Comment: Don't use getLastKnownLocation.  It will return null the VAST majority of the time-  it only returns a value if something else was recently using location.  Instead, request a location update and use that.